# why do I not have java runtime even when I downloaded the most recent java version?

Tags: java, runtime

When I put  in java -version into Terminal. I'm told that there isn't java runtime present even though java works fine in safari and I just downloaded the most recent version of Java

Comment: Did you set `JAVA_HOME`? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: difference between jre and jdk ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME or JRE_HOME and add it to your PATH.

In MacOS and UNIX you can change your .bashrc file (in your home folder) and add the lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/java/home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

the variables are exported automatically when you start the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of Java did you install?

There's JDK (For Developers, which contains all needed Stuff to code), but I don't know if it contains JRE (Java Runtime Environment). Try to download especially JRE and try again.

Comment: ok yeah that worked thanks. I just got a new mac and completely forgot that JDK is separate

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - **FOR WINDOWS**

To set up JDK (Java Development Kit) -- Ofcourse you need to install java first

1. Right click on My computer
2. Go to properties
3. Select Advanced System Settings

Now Under Advanced tab Click on Environment Variables 
There will be 2 options - User variables and System Variables

**In User Variables Click on New...**

1. Set Variable name as PATH (in capitals)
2. Set Variable value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin (path to bin folder where java is installed)

**Similarly in System Variables click on New...**

1. Set Variable name as JAVA_HOME (in capitals)
2. Set Variable value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
3. Hit OK

***Close the Command Prompt and re-open it. ! imp <--
Now write " javac -version "***

Comment: You seem to know what OS he is on, but I don't see it specified in the question. Indeed, he mentions using Safari which is not commonly used on Windows.

Comment: oops , i presumed its windows ! my bad